# In Clion how to navigate to all compile error?

Tags: clion

When I compile a big project and say there are many compile errors. Is there is a way in CLion to jump to the next error?

Comment: FYI, if you used [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) it would be very easy; see its [compilation mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html). You might consider switching to `emacs` for that very reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Messages pane, there are two buttons on the left toolbar that allow jumping to the next / previous error. Additionally, those are associated with shortcuts.

[image]